# Excel VBA Only Add Numbers to Variant/string

Tags: vba, excel

Can see similar questions to mine but not close enough so, here goes:

I need to add the contents of a cell to a string or variant but to strip off any letters or characters but cannot interfere with the contents of the cell.

A typical example of what the cell might contain is WD/99999999 but I only need the 99999999. However, the length of the number might vary and the letters and characters it might be proceeded by might vary but will always be letters or characters.

Once this has been achieved, I need to check if the number is 4 digits or less and if so add a "*" to the front.

Thanks in advance, all help received so far in this project is much appreciated!

Jamie

Comment: are they always separated by / or some other character?

Comment: Are these stored in A1,A2,A3 etc or ? I think example input/desired output is required

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your raw string is stored in the variable "s".

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim result As String

result = ""
For i = 1 To Len(s)
    If Mid(s, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(s, i, 1) <= "9" Then
        result = result + Mid(s, i, 1)
    End If
Next
```

Now only the digits are stored in the string variable "result".
You can then check if Len of result is 4 or less.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim someText As String

someText = "WD/99999999"
someText = GetNumber(someText)

If Len(someText) <= 4 Then
    someText = "*" & someText
End If
```

And function

```
Function GetNumber(strText)
    Dim strBuild As String

    For i = 1 To Len(strText)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(strText, i, 1)) Then
            strBuild = strBuild & Mid(strText, i, 1)
        End If
    Next

    GetNumber = strBuild
End Function
```

Comment: Run Flow Error '6' - Overflow on intReturn = strBuild

Comment: Fixed. Number too large for integer

Comment: Lovely, that's sorted it thanks with a couple of minor tweaks.